# Checking if field is populated in database

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Still learning ColdFusion best practices and came across one that I think I could do better

I'm running CF10 and basically have a process where a user fills out spreadsheet with 20 columns and 5 are not required. Of the 5 that are not required, 2 (blah1 and blah2) requires no data to be filled out and if no data is filled out, then it gets inserted as NULL.

Final and separate process is basically reading the fields in each column on the table and if it sees NULL for the 2 (blah1 and blah2 columns) then it will be set to default values, but if it does see any value, then it will use what was entered as the values.

Here is what I have:

```
<cfif Len(blah1)>
 <cfset blah1 = "#default1#" />
<cfelse>
 <cfset blah1 = "default1" />
</cfif>

<cfif Len(blah2)>
 <cfset blah2 = "#default2#" />
<cfelse>
 <cfset blah2 = "default2" />
</cfif>
```

Is using Len() the best way to check if any data is populated in a field in a table?

Comment: Fills out a spreadsheet?

Comment: There is more to input validation than checking to see if anything was entered.  You have to check for proper data types.  Also, for char and varchar fields, you have to ensure the user doesn't try to submit 20 characters into a varchar(19) field.

Comment: I have seen len() and `field NEQ ""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to perform the check in the database then yes, `len()` is the best way. If there's any possibility of a user entering just spaces, you check `len(trim())`

Since you're on CF10 you can write your code using a ternary operator to simplify things a bit

```
<cfset blah1 = len(qryName.blah1) ? qryName.default1: 'default1'>
```

You'll want to scope your variables when they're part of the variables scope, so prefix `blah1` with the queryName if that's where it's coming from. Also when setting a variable You don't need to use `"##"` you can just set something to the variable. Without using a ternary operator you'd just need

```
<cfif Len(qryName.blah1)>
  <cfset blah1 = qryName.default1 />
<cfelse>
  <cfset blah1 = "default1" />
</cfif>
```